# Scanf unknown number of integers

Tags: c

I am trying to solve an exercise of a course I'm taking and we're just in the beginning so using `realloc`, `malloc`, and other dynamic allocation function is not used here.

First input will be euro - dollar rate, for ex. `1.37`. The rest of the input will be in dollars that will need to be converted to euros and in the end a total row.

For example for the input `1.37`, `2`, `3`, `4` the result will be:

```
$   Euro
2   2.74
3   4.11
4   5.48
9   12.33
```

Without using dynamic allocation how can I accept an unknown number of integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to keep all of them. Just keep two sum values which are updated with every iteration...